# clickable html links in python

Tags: html, python-2.7, hyperlink

I am looking for a way to make a link clickable.  I'm using python 2.7.9 and have written a program to help my students.  Each indicator of their writing has a link attached for further help.  Right now, they are just printed and the students need to copy and paste the file.  How do I make them clickable.  Opening in another window would be ideal, but I really just want to have the link open.

as an example:

```
tx="# of pronouns"
        t1=iTest["pro"]
        t2=round(100*t1/number_of_words,1)
        tc='''      
                    You are not to use inclusive pronouns
                    in academic writing.
                    Please go to http://owll.massey.ac.nz/academic-writing/1st-vs-3rd-person.php to review.'''
        row="<tr><td ><pro>"+tx+"</pro></td> <td>"+str(t1)+"</td> <td>"+str(t2)+"%</td> <td>"+tc+"</td>"
        if t1>0: fo.writelines(row) #only print this row if there are personal pronouns
```

Comment: Look up the HTML Address tag <a href="httpz://owll.massey.ac.nz/..."> Please click here. </a> (Change the httpz to http.  I did this just for the comment so it does not show up as a link on StackOverflow.)

Comment: What Daniel is trying to say is that you cannot just put the 'link' as a piece of text, it needs to be inside the HTML Address tag. HTML is a markup language that converts text into a format that a computer can understand and then 'draw' that text on the screen in a way a human can recognise what it is. So, in this case, the <a> tag will change your 'http....' text into an actual clickable link, so the browser will 'render' it as a link and a human will see a link and no the raw text and go 'oh ok, I can click this'. :)

Comment: Thank you all for your help!  It works wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve something like this:

```html
<a href="http://owll.massey.ac.nz/academic-writing/1st-vs-3rd-person.php">
    http://owll.massey.ac.nz/academic-writing/1st-vs-3rd-person.php
</a>
```